# Unable to find docker image

Tags: docker, nvidia-docker, retinanet

I am new to docker and learning about it recently. When I was trying to use it for one of my assignments. I got the following error of which I did not find any good solution anywhere.
I have properly installed nvidia-docker and build the image before trying out the following command as given in the [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker).
The nvidia-docker version is:

```
ii  nvidia-docker  1.0.1-1  amd64  NVIDIA Docker container tools
```

This is the error I got after running the above command.

```
Unable to find image 'retinanet:latest' locallydocker: Error response from 
daemon: pull access denied for retinanet, repository does not exist or may 
require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
```

The following is what I got after building the image.

```
$ sudo docker build -t retinanet:latest retinanet/
Sending build context to Docker daemon  208.9kB
Step 1/3 : FROM nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch:19.05-py3
---> 7e98758d4777
Step 2/3 : COPY . retinanet/
---> Using cache
---> a32277843b1f
Step 3/3 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -e retinanet/
---> Using cache
---> a0195cf77814
Successfully built a0195cf77814
Successfully tagged retinanet:latest
```

The following is the result I got after docker images.

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
<none>                   <none>              7cd7d8e7cedc        2 days ago          
7.59GB
nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch   19.09-py3           9d6f9ccfbe31        6 weeks ago         9.15GB
nvidia/cuda              9.0-base            1443caa429f9        7 weeks ago         137MB
retinanet                latest              a0195cf77814        7 weeks ago         7.59GB
nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch   19.07-py3           71df86c191f8        3 months ago        8.32GB
nvcr.io/nvidia/pytorch   19.05-py3           7e98758d4777        5 months ago        7.55GB
```

When I use the command

```
 docker run -ti retinanet:latest
```

The workspace is created but I get the following warnings which indicates that I am not utilizing the GPU facility.

```
WARNING: The NVIDIA Driver was not detected.  GPU functionality will not be available.
Use 'nvidia-docker run' to start this container; see https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/nvidia-docker .

NOTE: MOFED driver for multi-node communication was not detected.
  Multi-node communication performance may be reduced.

NOTE: The SHMEM allocation limit is set to the default of 64MB.  This may be
insufficient for PyTorch.  NVIDIA recommends the use of the following flags:
nvidia-docker run --ipc=host ...
```

Note: I followed the solution to this [link](http://docker%20run%20--rm%20-v%20%22$(pwd)%22:/foo%20busybox) but it is not helpful in my case.
Any ideas and suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.